# Parabola having focus $(1,2)$ touches both axes. Find the equation of directrix.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

Parabola having focus $(1,2)$ touches both axes. Find the equation of directrix.
As perpendicular tangents meet at directrix, the directrix passes through origin. So the directrix has equation of the form $y+mx=0$. How do I get the $m$ ?

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/767631/focus-of-parabola-with-two-tangents

Answer (score 3):

Use the property: The reflection of focus about any tangent of the parabola lies on the directrix.

Hence, taking it's reflection along Y axis, we get $(-1,2)$ and taking it's reflection along X axis, we get $(1,-2)$. Since both the points lie on the directrix of the equation, the equation of the directrix is the line joining these two points.

The directrix hence comes out as $y+2x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The directrix must be perpendicular to the line joining the points **(0,0)** and **(1,2)**.